# DATE and TIME function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

5/16/2020  15:12 = Saturday(6) = A

Formula:

```
=IF(A=6,(DATE(YEAR(R13),MONTH(R13),DAY(R13)+2)))
```

This results to `5/18/2020  0:00`

I would like for the result to be `5/18/2020  8:00`

Is there a way to merge `=TIME(8,0,0)` into the formula above?

Comment: `=IF(A=6,(DATE(YEAR(R13),MONTH(R13),DAY(R13)+2)+TIME(8,0,0)))`

Comment: @ScottCraner, you are awesome! appreciate your assistance on this one!